# Solving recurrence relation with floor and square root

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I would like to solve the following recurrence:
$$a_0 = 1$$
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + \lfloor\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\rfloor$$
Some observations I've made:

- The sequence increases by a sequence of increasing numbers (obviously), with each positive integer being the difference between the terms of the sequence either twice or thrice, since $\frac{(m+1)^2 - m^2}{m} = 2 + \frac{1}{m}$
- If $a_n = m^2$, then the relation above means means that $a_{n+k} = m^2 + km$, for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3$

However I cannot see how to generalize those observations further to get a closed form of the recurrence.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A002984

Comment: What makes you think there's a nice closed form ?

Comment: Nothing, really. Perhaps there is none, but I definitely felt like there was more to say about the sequence than the couple of things I've mentioned--if not a closed form than some simplified recurrence.